# Нужно записать слова в массив

Tags: c++

У меня есть файл в котором содержится N строк. Каждая строка содержит М слов.
Мне нужно что бы каждое отдельное слово было присвоено своей переменой. 
У меня уже получилось записать 2 слова в разные переменные. Но это произошло "случайно", я не понял принципа работы.
Мне не понятно как присваивать слова переменным или элементам массива, если число слов в строке буде произвольным.

```
{
size_t counter = 0;
string line; // чтение из файла
char * cstr = new char [line.length()+1];
ifstream readFile;
readFile.open(fileName, ios_base::out);
if (!readFile.is_open())
std::cout << "ERROR! " << fileName << " isnt open!" << endl;
else
while (std::getline(readFile,line))
{
    counter++;
    strcpy (cstr, line.c_str());
    char * chek = std::strtok (cstr,"\t");
    chek = std::strtok(NULL,"\t");
    int tempTime = std::atoi(cstr);
    int tempCheck = std::atoi(chek);
    inputTime.push_back(tempTime);      // запись в вектор времени
    avgChek.push_back(tempCheck);       // зпись в вектор среднего чека

}
readFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Если вы уже используете std::, вам вполне может подойти и std::list<std::string>. Для каждого слова создаете новую строку и в вектор ее.

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю использовать возможности стандартной библиотеки C++:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> v;

    // Читаем из стандартного потока ввода 
    // (можно заменить на нужный, например, файловый) в вектор
    std::copy( 
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), // начальный итератор ввода
        {}, // конечный итератор ввода (вызывается конструктор по умолчанию)
        std::back_inserter(v) // итератор вставки в конец контейнера
    );

    // Выводим из вектора в стандартный поток вывода 
    // (можно заменить на нужный, например, файловый)
    std::copy(  
        v.begin(), // итератор начала вектора
        v.end(), // итератор конца вектора
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " ") // итератор вывода в поток
    );
}
```

[Пример выполнения кода.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vTuSLdxXSOhTgETz)

Comment: Отформатируйте, не понятно же!

Comment: @Cerbo что именно Вам не понятно, и какого рода форматирование Вы считаете приемлемым?

Comment: Мне все понятно, но читать в одну строчку не удобно.

Comment: @Cerbo имхо, не вижу здесь ни одной чрезмерно длинной строки кода. Выносить каждый аргумент функции на отдельную строку не считаю целесообразным. Однако, было не плохо, если бы Вы всё же привели пример объективно более удачного форматирования.

Comment: Теперь можно добавить пояснения для каждой строчки, зачем и почему

Comment: @Cerbo запятые на новой строке - ужас же! Что Вы творите!? Где так пишут?

Comment: Запятые в начале строки это мое изобретене (не утверждаю что я первый), они во-первых слева создают ровную колонку что уменьшает визуальный шум, во-вторых удобно закомментировать параметры функций так как в 90% случаях вначале идут важные параметры, а в конце те которые могут быть удалены.

Comment: @Cerbo для какого-нибудь построчного `diff`а это может быть полезным. Но для кода, имхо, предпочтительнее вариант запятой в конце слова, как принято и в обычном тексте.

Comment: @alexout В том то и дело что код не обычный текст. Вообще я придерживаюсь табличного форматирования, суть которого в том что строки отбиваются в колонки, в одних колонках элементы поторяются, в других нет. В результате одного взгляда достаточно чтобы понять что происходит, удобно также искать что-нибудь. Причем колонки составляются из всего что есть включая запятые, скобки и прочее. В результате такого тотального *отабличивания* потребовалось и запятые в колонки отбивать, они же повторяются, но оказалось что справа запятые отбивать неудобно...

Comment: @alexout ... так как имена параметров, например, могут меняться, много суеты из-за этого. В результате, чтобы не отказываться от *отбаличивания* я пришел к выводу что запятые должны быть слева.

Comment: @Cerbo: Но всё же автор ответа имеет право на такое форматирование, как _ему_ нравится.

Comment: @VladD Безусловно имеет, я и не оспариваию этого. Я мог бы и сам отформатировать как считаю нужным, но так как автор не я, то и решил попросить его.